# How can I change the format of this date

Tags: java, date

I have a date like 24May2018 and want to change it to 24-05-2018. I tried using SimpleDateFormat but it is throwing UnParseable Date. I have tried the following code:-

```
SimpleDateFormat inputDate=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy",Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat outputDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.US);
Date parseFormat=new SimpleDateFormat
Date date=inputDate.parse(val);
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]....

Comment: Try with `"ddMMMyyyy"`  .

Comment: Why do you expect the pattern ``ddMMyyyy`` to match a String in the form of ``24May2018 ``?

Comment: If you're using Java 8 or above, switch to using `java.time` packages, not the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. If older java, it's best to use the backward compatibility libraries for that if at all possible.

Comment: Write a junit test for parsing to determine if date is parsable and try several formulations of your date format, output should tell You which is the right match.

Comment: @PanBrambor ...or simply use the correct pattern?

Comment: @f1sh ofcourse, but junit is a way to find out whats wrong by yourself, overall a great habbit to have.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The example in the question is close to minimal, it’s close to complete (the declaration of `val` is not there, but its value is in the text, so this is not serious) and a trivial compile error prevents it from being verifiable as it stands. Not bad for a fairly new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The InputFormat must be:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputDate=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy",Locale.US);
```

because the length of month is 3 character

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java8+, I would strongly suggest to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library, if not, then you can use [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library which is equivalent to java.time API :

```
String date = "24May2018";
LocalDate ldt = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.US));
String result = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.US));
=>24-05-2018
```

Comment: This requires Java 8+?

Comment: exactly @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but if you are not using Java 8+ you can use [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

Comment: Sure.  You might want to make your answer more complete then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
    String stringDate = "24May2018";

    SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat outputParser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    Date temp;
    String outputDate;

    try {
        temp = inputParser.parse(stringDate);
        outputDate = outputParser.format(temp);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```